# Sieve of Eratosthenes prime numbers up to a million c++

Tags: c++, sieve-of-eratosthenes

So I need help with my code. For some reason it keeps crashing when I enter a number past 500,000. Here is the exact assignment.

> Implement the Sieve of Eratosthenes and use it to find all prime
>   numbers less than or equal to one million. Use the result to
>   prove Goldbach's Conjecture for all even integers between four and
>   one million, inclusive.
>
> Implement a function with the following declaration:
>
> ```
> void sieve(int array[], int num);
> ```
>
> This function takes an integer array as its argument. The array
>   should be initialized to the values 1 through 1000000. The
>   function modifies the array so that only the prime numbers remain;
>   all other values are zeroed out.
>
> This function must be written to accept an integer array of any
>   size. You must should output for all primes numbers between 1 and
>   1000000, but when I test your function it may be on an array of a
>   different size.
>
> Implement a function with the following declaration:
>
> ```
> void goldbach(int array[], int num);
> ```
>
> This function takes the same argument as the previous function
>   and displays each even integer between 4 and 1000000 with two
>   prime numbers that add to it.
>
> The goal here is to provide an efficient implementation. This
>   means no multiplication, division, or modulus when determining if
>   a number is prime. It also means that the second function must find
>   two primes efficiently.
>
> Output for your program:
>
> All prime numbers between 1 and 1000000
>   and all even numbers between 4 and 1000000 and the two prime
>   numbers that sum up to it.
>
> DO NOT provide output or a session record for this project!

And here is what I have so far. If anyone could help me that would be great.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void sieve (int array[], int num);

int main()
{
    int num;
    cout << "Enter a number to calculate up to." << endl;
    cin>> num;
    if ( num < 2 )
        return 0;

    int array[num];
    array[0]= array[1]= 0;
    for ( int i= 2; i < num; ++i )
        array[i]= i;
    sieve(array,num);
    for (int i=0; i<num; i++)
        if (array[i] > 0)
            cout << array[i] <<" "<<endl;
    cout<<endl;

    return 0;
}

void sieve( int array[], int num )
{
    for ( int i= 0; i < num; ++i )
    {
        if ( array[i] != 0 )
        {
            for ( int j= i+i; j < num; j += i )
            {
                array[j]= 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `int array[num];` Use a `std::vector<int> array(num);` instead. Your stack size is probably too small to allocate such a big array.

Comment: I have not learned how to use vectors yet. But thank you for the response!

Comment: Alternatively you can use `int* array = new int[n];` and manage the allocated heap memory yourself. But be careful with that.

Comment: Have a look at [these search results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bc%2b%2b%5dstack%20overflow%20VLA) as well please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why your code crashes is that you're using VLA allocation for the array here

```
int array[num];
```

It's used to allocate `num` int elements of the stack, which is most probably too small to hold a million of `int` values.

You should note it's not a standard c++ feature, but an extension provided by a number of compiler implementations.

To fix this there are three alternatives:

1. You configure the stack size used for your program to be big enough to hold the number of `int` elements (this is OS dependend)
2. You use a `std::vector<int> array(num);` instead, that allocates these elements on the heap memory
3. You allocate the necessary memory on the heap yourself using `int* array = new int[num];` and `delete [] array;` at the end of your program (I wouldn't recommend this solution, because it's prone to make silly mistakes regarding the proper memory management)

Comment: I do not understand how to implement the vector into my program. And thank you for responding!

Comment: @Bawad Just as shown, and pass [`std::vector::data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) to the other functions as parameter.

Comment: @Bawad Which error? Did you miss to `#include <vector>`?

Comment: I am not playing possum sir lol. I just do not understand. i am sure you are very smart guy. I am very new to programming . @πάντα ῥεῖ

Comment: @Bawad So why did you accept this answer then? What's your error in particular? What didn't you understand?

Comment: You tried explaining it to me several times and i failed to understand so i gave up

Comment: @Bawad So please what didn't you understand? How to use `new[]` and `delete[]`? How should I know, if you even don't express yourself clearly?

Comment: Yes i do not understand how to use new and delete

Comment: @Bawad Exactly using that syntax shown above in my answer. Did you try it? What was the problem, it didn't work for you actually? Oh wait, I made a typo. Fixed it now sorry.

Comment: I am receiving the error...error:expected initializer before 'new' and i typed this instead of int array[num], 
    int* array new int[num];

Comment: @Bawad Sorry about misguiding you for the syntax. But anyway I have the feeling [phoxis answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29321369/1413395) below gives some useful hints how to reduce array sizes that need to be allocated actually.

Comment: its alright man thanks for spending two days on this code with me

Answer (score 1):

As I see this is an assignment, you need to write your own code, but I have a few ideas to reduce the amount of memory significantly.

Why don't you use array of bits instead ?

Do something like

```
#define IS_SET(x) (arr[(x)>>3] & (0x01 << ((x) & 0x07)))
#define SET(x) (arr[(x)>>3] |= (0x01 << ((x) & 0x07)))
```

and define `arr` as an array of `char`. This will make the memory utilization 8 folds down. For C++ you can use `bool` might not get you the lowest possible memory usage.

First clear out all the char elements. Then for each number set bits using `SET(x)` an once all marking is done. If `IS_SET(x)` evaluates false then `x` is prime.

Saves large amount of memory.

**EDIT1:**

Another trick to cut 50% of the memory required is not to retain space for the even numbers. Start with `i=3` and always increment using `i+=2` and mark the bit arrays. While reading do the same.

**EDIT2:**

If you can find a series which skips the integers which are multiple of two or three or both, then you can save around 30% more memory. In fact you can make such a series and skip storing and marking for the multiples of two and three or both.