# Efficiency and array crashing

Tags: c++, arrays

Whenever I run this code and enter a number over 500,000, the program crashes. Also is there away to make this more simple/efficient without using: vectors, multiplication, division and %. Thanks a lot!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int get_primes(int array[], int num);
void sieve(int array[], int num);
void goldbach(int primes[], int nprimes, int num);
void show(int array[], int num);

int main()
{
int num;
cout << "Enter a number to calculate up to." << endl;
cin>>num;
if ( num < 2 )
    return 0;

int array[num];
array[0]= array[1]= 0;
for ( int i= 2; i < num; ++i )
    array[i]= i;

int nprimes = get_primes(array, num);

show(array, nprimes);

goldbach(array, nprimes, num);

return 0;
}

void show(int array[], int num)
{
for (int i=0; i<num; i++)
    if (array[i] > 0)
        cout << array[i] << " "<< endl;
cout << endl;
}

int get_primes(int array[], int num)
{

sieve(array, num);


int pos = 0;
for (int i = 2; i < num; ++i)
    if (array[i] > 0)
        array[pos++] = array[i];

return pos;
}

void sieve( int array[], int num )
{
for ( int i= 0; i < num; ++i )
{
    if ( array[i] > 0 )
    {
        for ( int j = i+i; j < num; j += i )
        {
            array[j] = 0;
        }
        }
    }
}


void goldbach(int primes[], int nprimes, int num)
{

int a;
for (int a = 4; a<=num; a+=2)
{
    bool found = false;
    int i, j;


    for (i = 0; !found && i < nprimes && primes[i];  ++i)
        for (j = 0; !found && j < nprimes && primes[i]; ++j)

            {
                found = a == (primes[i] + primes[j]);

                if (found)
         cout << a << '\t' << primes[i] << " + " << primes[j] <<endl;
            }

    if (!found)
        cout << a << "\tnot found" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly is it crashing? Can you include a stack trace or line number?

Comment: See this Q&A where it's explained what's going on: [Sieve of Eratosthenes prime numbers up to a million c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320738/sieve-of-eratosthenes-prime-numbers-up-to-a-million-c/29321062#29321062)

Comment: the number that it will stop outputting at would be 19739

Comment: @Bawad It depends on the stack size available for your program what's the biggest number that can be allocated.

Comment: at 500,000 the program runs. at 600,000 the program crashes

Comment: You asked this **exact same question yesterday?**

Comment: @egrunin I didn't even notice that it was the same OP :-P ...

Comment: yes i did but i did not understand the answers that were being given due to my lack of knowledge in c++. I worked more on the code itself and i have gotten farther into the program however i have not fixed the crashing problem. @egrunin

Comment: @Bawad You should read the answer thoroughly. I gave you an alternative how to fix it besides using `std::vector` (for whatever reason you keep refusing this solution).

Comment: You need to keep working on that page, putting your questions in the comments. This one is going to get closed very soon. We understand that you're a student, but you're almost asking for us to write your code for you.

Comment: i can not use vectors because my professor has not yet taught it and he will accuse me of cheating

Comment: @Bawad Himmelarschundzwirnnochamalzefix! I've explained which alternatives can be used besides `std::vector<>`. Are you playing possum?

Comment: @Bawad If your professor thinks that using `vector` is cheating, then what about this?: `int array[num];`  That would be considered cheating as well, since standard C++ does not have such arrays, where the number of entries is a variable.

Comment: How is using `std::vector` cheating if you took the time to learn and apply it yourself? I would commend that initiative.

Comment: If I was you professor and you used a vector I would think this person is reading around the subject

Answer (score 1):

Saying `int array[num]` is saying "allocate `num * sizeof(int)` bytes from the stack."

So it might be that your stack is only one megabyte in size, and when you ask for more you hit an underflow condition.

Comment: Also this is called VLA and isn't a standard c++ feature.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
int array[num];
```

to

```
int* array = new int[num];
```

and change all the function arguments from using

```
int array[]
```

to

```
int* array
```

you will still be able to access the pointers normally like array[i].

I would recommend you to look up stack vs heap memory in C++ to understand why this works, and to read up on pointers too.

Comment: Considering he is a beginner, shouldn't you explain how to delete the memory as well?

Comment: @NeilKirk Yes, that is true, but I didn't want to confuse him too much, if he makes these changes, the code will at least run, and then delete apon exiting. If the code was a little more complex and had heap allocation inside a function other than main that was called multiple times, then that would start causing memory leaks, but the main function with the array alocate only runs once, I know its bad practice but I just wanted his code to run first, then for him to read up on heap vs stack later. This is my first answer post on stackoverflow btw.